# Not returning the expected result from the MVC controller - parseerror

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm implementing the login form and validating the user info through ajax call and on successful am redirecting into the particular view as follows.

This is ajax call to signIn form.

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location,
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        // redirect will happen automatically
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        debugger;
    }
});

I am getting 'status' as "parseerror"
```

In controller : I am validating and if its success then I am calling another controller as follows

```
if (result.IsSucessCode) {
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Search", new { Area = "TestFolder" }); 
}
```

In Index search:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var model = searchPL.InitializeSearch();
    return View(model);
}
```

The problem is, after this (return View(model);) it's firing to the ajax error function instead of success method / redirect to the "Search Index" view.

Appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Instead of returning from controller after validating try redirecting from ajax call in success method

Edit 
you can also use like this

```
if (result.IsSucessCode)
{
 return JavaScript("window.location = '/Search/Index'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is, it will not firing the success method and it will fire the error method with all the model of the view.